# Weird date behavior?

Tags: java, date

```
life  = 91
today = System.currentTimeMillis()
expireDate = new Date(today + life * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

`new Date(today)` returns today's date `Wed Nov 28 15:21:01 GMT+05:30 2012` as expected

Why does `new Date(expireDate)` return `Tue Nov 20 05:17:16 GMT+05:30 2012` which is much prior to today's date, when I actually expect a date ahead?

Answer (score 6):

It is because the value you add to today is an int and it actually goes beyond the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and when that happens, it starts back from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

In order to fix this, declare one of the values as `long`. For instance, `3600` could be `3600l`.

Comment: Since today is long, I think this is not the case. today should be cast to a long, and then added to life*24*3600*1000).

Comment: life should cast to a long*, but I did not think of the multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int life = 91;
long today = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date expireDate = new Date(today + life * 24 * 3600 * 1000L);
System.out.println(expireDate);
```

prints

```
Wed Feb 27 10:03:32 GMT 2013
```

Note: I use `1000L` to prevent an overflow, so would making `life` a `long`.